# PHP: Search MYSQL database between datetime but use the date only?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a column in MYSQL that stores the datetime like so:

```
2017-08-18 08:59:53
2017-08-18 07:59:00
```

I can search the database and return the results between the datetime column like so:

```
$from = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_GET['from']));
$to = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_GET['to']));

$sql1="SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE mydate>='$to' and mydate<='$from'";
```

This works fine as long as I search like this:

```
2017-08-18 08:59:53
```

But what I need to be able to do is to search like this:

```
2017-08-18
```

and still get the same result when I search.

I don't want to use the time in my search string/query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try mysql `date()` function like:

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE date(mydate)>='$to' and date(mydate)<='$from'";
```

mysql `date()` function returns only date part from datetime column in default `Y-m-d` format.

Answer (score 2):

You are very close. If you want to search a `DATETIME` or other datestamp column for matches to a particular day, do this:

```
WHERE mydate >= DATE(whatever_first_day)
  AND mydate  < DATE(whatever_last_day) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

This searches for everything on the date mentioned in `whatever_first_day`, starting with midnight on that date, and everything up to, but not including (`<`), midnight on the day after `whatever_last_day`.

This way of searching is [sargable: it can use an index on the `mydate` column](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

You could also use

```
 WHERE DATE(mydate) >= DATE(whatever_first_day)
   AND DATE(mydate) <= DATE(whatever_last_day)
```

but that is not sargable.

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT * FROM `Table` WHERE date_format(mydate,"%Y-%m-%d")>='$to' and date_format(mydate,"%Y-%m-%d")<='$from'";
```